# Why does RANDOM() in a SQLite CTE JOIN behave differently to other RDBMSs?

Tags: sql, sqlite, random, common-table-expression

`RANDOM()` values in a Common Table Expression (CTE) join aren't behaving as expected in [SQLite](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/71568/18).

**SQL:**

```
WITH
  tbl1(n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2),
  tbl2(n, r) AS (SELECT n, RANDOM() FROM tbl1)
SELECT * FROM tbl2 t1 CROSS JOIN tbl2 t2;
```

**Sample SQLite results:**

```
n   r                       n   r
1   7058971975145008000     1   8874103142384122000
1   1383551786055205600     2   8456124381892735000
2   2646187515714600000     1   7558324128446983000
2   -1529979429149869800    2   7003770339419606000
```

The random numbers in each column are all different. But a `CROSS JOIN` repeats rows - so I expected 2 pairs of the same number in each column - which *is* the case in [PostgreSQL](http://rextester.com/JDABN73230), [Oracle 11g](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ae2cc8/348) and [SQL Server 2014](http://rextester.com/HVHZ38463) (when using a row-based seed).

**Sample PostgreSQL / Oracle 11g / SQL Server 2014 results:**

```
n   r                   n   r
1   0.117551110684872   1   0.117551110684872
1   0.117551110684872   2   0.221985165029764
2   0.221985165029764   1   0.117551110684872
2   0.221985165029764   2   0.221985165029764
```

**Questions**

1. Can the behaviour in SQLite be explained? Is it a bug?
2. Is there a way for Table B in a CTE (based on Table A in the same CTE) to have an additional column of randomly generated numbers, which will remain fixed when used in a `JOIN`?

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is here. SQLite and and SQL Server are 2 completely different RDBMS. Different behaviour between the 2 should be expected; they aren't going to behave exactly the same with everything.

Comment: Sure but why aren't we seeing pairs of the same random number in their results?

Comment: According to the SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rand-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): *Repetitive calls of RAND() with the same seed value return the same results.* Having the same number returned throughout your query is to be expected.

Comment: But the seed value wasn't specified so I expected them all to be different: *If seed is not specified, the SQL Server Database Engine assigns a seed value at random.*

Comment: ...Looks like the random `RAND()` seed only gets put in once even though it is being used for different rows. Fair enough I guess - have now updated the question. The issue still remains for SQLite though.

Comment: It does assign a random seed value, but that random seed value will be the same (random) seed value through the entire query. I have no experience with SQLite, however, so i can't answer for how that works.

Comment: In SQL Server, some of the non-deterministic functions, such as RAND() and GETDATE() are evaluated only once per query, that is to say, they do not change their values as the query is running.  If you want 'randomness' in SQL Server, NEWID() can be used e.g SORT BY NEWID()

Comment: @Cato . . . Thati s not exactly right.  Check out my answer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  - I read that with interest thanks.  Which part do you think 'is not exactly right' You seem to have said very similar things in your answer

Comment: @Cato . . . Once per query and once per expression are quite different things.  Look at the examples in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is rather long and rambling -- not a single question.  But, it is interesting and I learned something.

This statement is not true:

> SQL Server assigns a random seed to the RAND() function: When used in
>   a SELECT, it is only seeded once rather than for each row.

SQL Server has the concept of run-time constant functions.  These are functions that are pulled from the compiled query and executed once *per expression* at the beginning of the query.  The most prominent examples are `getdate()` (and related date/time functions) and `rand()`.

You can readily see this if you run:

```
select rand(), rand()
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(x);
```

Each column has the same values, but the values between the columns are different.

Most databases -- including SQLite -- have the more intuitive interpretation of `rand()`/`random()`.  (As an personal note, a "random" function that returns the same value on each row is highly counter-intuitive.)  Each time it is called you get a different value.  For SQL Server, you would typically use an expression using `newid()`:

```
select rand(), rand(), rand(checksum(newid()))
from (values (1), (2), (3)) v(x);
```

As for your second question, it *appears* that SQLite materializes recursive CTEs.  So this does what you want:

```
WITH tbl1(n) AS (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
     ),
     tbl2(n, r) AS (
       SELECT n, RANDOM()
       FROM tbl1
       union all
       select *
       from tbl2
       where 1=0
      )
SELECT *
FROM tbl2 t1 CROSS JOIN tbl2 t2;
```

I have seen no documentation that this is the case, so use at your own risk.  [Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c7bY1Uv5omcNp5QwVs6avB/0) is a DB-Fiddle.

And, for the record, this seems to work in SQL Server as well.  I just learned something!

EDIT:

As suggested in the comment, the materialization may not always happen.  It does seem to apply to two references at the same level:

```
WITH tbl1(n) AS (
      SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2),
     tbl2(n, r) AS (
       SELECT n, RANDOM()
       FROM tbl1
       union all
       select *
       from tbl2
       where 1=0
      )
SELECT t2a.r, count(*)
FROM tbl2 t2a left JOIN
     tbl2 t2b
     on t2a.r = t2b.r
GROUP BY t2a.r;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to research this and for the suggested workaround, which seems to work in the context of the question asked. However, a further subselect doesn't seem to be giving the results I'd hoped for - see [this DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/onmj3sfnfqWydmhUfHPacq/0): Would expect the counts here to each be 1 if the CTE was truly materialized.

Comment: @SteveChambers . . . One of the most interesting questions I've seen in a while.  Interestingly, the code does work with the table references in the same `FROM`.  In any case, this is undocumented behavior and I don't see a way to force SQLite to materialize CTEs.  By the way, for some other databases, materialization is the default option.